# HTML5 Game Engine - JavaScript Animation

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, game-engine

JavaScript Animation is not working at all!

This HTML5 Game Engine should allow a user to move an image element "matador" with buttons in order to dodge another image element "bull" which should be constantly moving across a 900px by 600px container.

I am not sure what is going wrong in the JavaScript to keep the image elements from moving.

If you can figure out the error in these functions, you are a super genius. :)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<!-- PAGE TITLE -->
<head> <title> MATADOR </title> </head>

<!-- GAME ELEMENTS --> <body style="background-color:red;">

<div id="container" style="background-color:#FC3; position: absolute;  
 width:900px; height:600px; left:0px; top:0px;">

<img src="matador.png" id="matador" style="position:relative; top:200px; 
 left:100px; width:60px; height:60px;" />

<img src="bull.jpg" id="bull" style="position:absolute; top:300px; 
left:20px; width:90px; height:90px;" />

<img id="matadorLife" src="matadorLife.png" style="position:absolute;  
top:515px; left:800px; width:60px; height:60px;" />

<div id="scoreId" style="position:absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; font-
family: impact; color:red; font-size: 50px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF;">  
</div>

<!-- Close "container" div --> 
</div>

<!-- Button Elements -->
<button type="button" onClick="MoveLeft();" style="position:absolute;  
top:600px; left:0px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact;  
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3;  
text-align: center;"> LEFT </button>

<button type="button" onClick="MoveRight();" style="position:absolute;   
top:600px; left:180px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact;   
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; 
text-align: center;"> RIGHT </button>

<button type="button" onClick="MoveDown();" style="position:absolute; 
top:600px; left:360px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact;    
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; 
text-align: center;"> DOWN </button>

<button type="button" onClick="MoveUp();" style="position:absolute; 
top:600px; left:540px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact;   
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; 
text-align:center;"> UP </button>

<!-- GAME ACTIONS -->
<script>

var matadorObj = document.getElementById("matador").style;
var xMatador = 0px; var yMatador = 0px;

var bullObj = document.getElementById("bull").style;
var xBull = 0px; var yBull = 200px;

var xSpeed = 10px; var ySpeed = 10px;

var score = 0; var speedInc = 0;

var lifeObj=document.getElementById("matadorLife").style;


document.onkeydown = KeyDownMoveIt;
function KeyDownMoveIt(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 37)
   xMatador = xMatador - 10 - speedInc*10;

   if (e.keyCode == 39)
   xMatador = xMatador + 10 + speedInc*10;

   if (e.keyCode == 38)
   yMatador = yMatador - 10 - speedInc*10;

   if (e.keyCode == 40)
   yMatador = yMatador + 10 + speedInc*10;

   if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   xMatador = 900 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   yMatador = 600 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;

   matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;}


function MoveRight()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   xMatador = xMatador + 60 + speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   xMatador = 900 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   yMatador = 600 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}


function MoveLeft()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   xMatador = xMatador - 60 - speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   xMatador = 900 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   yMatador = 600 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}


function MoveUp()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
  matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   yMatador = yMatador - 60 - speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   xMatador = 900 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   yMatador = 600 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}


function MoveDown()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
  yMatador = yMatador + 60 + speedInc*10;
   if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   xMatador = 900 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   yMatador = 600 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}


var timerA; 
window.onload = moveBull();
function moveBull(){

   if (xBull + xSpeed > 900 - 50)
   xSpeed = -5 * Math.random() - 5 - speedInc;

   if (xBull + xSpeed < 0)
   xSpeed = 5 * Math.random() + 5 + speedInc;

   if (yBull + ySpeed > 600 - 50)
   ySpeed = -5 * Math.random() - 5 - speedInc;

   if (yBull + ySpeed < 0)
   ySpeed = 5 * Math.random() + 5 + speedInc;

   xBull = xBull + xSpeed;
   yBull = yBull + ySpeed;

   bullObj.left = xBull;
   bullObj.top = yBull;

   speedInc = score * 0.01;

   if ((xMatador < xBull+50) && (xMatador+50 > xBull) && (yMatador <    
yBull+50) && (yMatador+50 > yBull)) {
      clearTimeout(timerB);
      matadorObj.src="matadorLost.png";
      bullObj.src="bullWon.png";
      document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "- GAME OVER -";
      document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor="red"; 
      lifeObj.visibility="hidden"; }

   if (score == 31) {clearTimeout(timerB);
      document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
      matadorObj.src="matadorWon.png";
      bullObj.src="bullLost.png";
      document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "- WINNER! -";}

   timerA = setTimeout("moveBull()", 30);}

var timerB;
window.onload = gameScore();
function gameScore() {  
   document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "MATADOR <br>" + score; 
   score++;
   timerB = setTimeout("gameScore()", 1000);}

</script>

</body> </html> <!-- END PROGRAM -->
```

Comment: `yMatador = 0px` it not valid it should be `yMatador = 0`

Comment: Dhiraj, thanks for posting!  

I replaced the '0px' with 0 value for all of the JavaScript variables :  
    
    <script>
    var xMatador = 0; var yMatador = 0; var xBull = 0; var yBull = 200;
    </script>

but the image elements still won't animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yMatador = 0px` is not valid. replace all such variables to something which look like these `yMatador = 0`.

This will result in

```
matadorObj.left = xMatador; // matadorObj.left = 10;
matadorObj.top = yMatador; // matadorObj.top = 10;

bullObj.left = xBull; // bullObj.left = 10;
bullObj.top = yBull; // bullObj.top = 10;
```

which are not valid as top and left need 'px' values so replace the above with these

```
matadorObj.left = xMatador + 'px';
matadorObj.top = yMatador + 'px';

bullObj.left = xBull + 'px';
bullObj.top = yBull + 'px';
```

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsbin.com/furise/2/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ay, this line

```
window.onload = gameScore();
```

should be

```
window.onload = gameScore;
```

without parenthesis. If they are there it will execute the function instead of referencing it. That means the result (undefined) will be assigned instead of function. Should work now! And also use 0 instead of 0px :)

Comment: `window.onload = gameScore()` is correct and `window.onload = gameScore` is wrong. Please check this http://jsbin.com/waqila/1/edit?html,js,output